# Wordpress: using "season" tag in permalink for a rugby club site

Tags: wordpress, customization, permalinks

I'm not an expert in Wordpress, thus I apologize if this question is too trivial or obvious.

I run my local rugby club's website with wordpress, and I'm fixing up permalinks. I'd like to achive a permalink form like `myclub.com/2013-14/myPostTitle`, which would perfectly fit our need, better than `myclub.com/2013/myPostTitle`

In other words, I want to add the concept of *season* as a custom permalink tag, so I would be able to define a rule like `/%season%/%postname%`

Is this possible?

Although it seems to be a useful customization for clubs, I haven't found any reference on the web.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try simple solution: add post category like "2013-14" and then set custom premalinks /%category%/%postname%/